# How do i convert my Dictionary into a string or parseable array that i can copy and paste or take to javascript database?

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing

Should of been easy.
I am making a Javascript React website using PostgreSQL as a database.

I made a C# webscrapper collecting data for some playing cards for a practice a making pokemon card style trading games.

I didnt want to make all the cards so i made a dictionairy with the basic data needed for my postgreSQL database im using.

Through the Insomnia program or the seed file. I want to add all the information in the dictionairy in an array or object containing an array format by copying and pasting my C# output into the Javascript website so i can quick install the cards. I could even use a json file.

I cannot figure out how to either save the data in a usable way or to get C# to print out the entire contents of the Dictionairy so i can just copy and paste it in and parse it or whatever.

HOW in C# can i just make it print everything in the dictionary with no gaps and in a useful way i can use again...Or maybe the more advanced option is to save the dict and somehow make javascript use that? I am avoiding just updating the database through c# on purpose.
So dumb question really. 'How do i make text?

BASIC CODE:

```
// Finds nodes
        HtmlNode[] nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]").ToArray();

        // index for dictionairy
        int startingIndex = 1;

        // Dictoinariry to store memberCards
        Dictionary<int, MemberCard> cards = new Dictionary<int, MemberCard>();

        foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("ITEM" + item.InnerHtml);

            // Get image node
            var img = item.SelectSingleNode("a/img");
            // Console.WriteLine(img.Attributes["src"].Value);

            // Get image src
            var src = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
            // Console.WriteLine("IMage src" + src);

            // Add missing data to source
            var fullSrcUrl = srcUrl + src;
            // Console.WriteLine("Full " + fullSrcUrl);

            // Get name
            var _name = item.SelectSingleNode("div/a/h3");

            var cardName = _name.InnerText + " Card";
            var membersName = _name.InnerText;

            Console.WriteLine($"CardName {cardName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"membersName {membersName}");

            string selectedPack = "PACK1";

            if (startingIndex > 117 && startingIndex < 235)
            {
                selectedPack = "PACK2";
            } else if (startingIndex > 234) {
                selectedPack = "PACK3";
            }


            cards.Add(startingIndex, new MemberCard() { cardName = cardName, imageUrl = fullSrcUrl, memberName = membersName, packType = selectedPack });
            startingIndex++;
        }

        // Print data
        foreach (MemberCard card in cards.Values)
        {
            var jsonStringCardName = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card.cardName);
            var jsonStringImageURL = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card.imageUrl);
            var jsonStringMemberName = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card.memberName);
            var jsonStringPackType = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card.packType);
            //Console.WriteLine("a" + jsonStringCardName + ",");
            //Console.WriteLine(jsonStringImageURL + ",");
           // Console.WriteLine(jsonStringMemberName + ",");
           Console.WriteLine(jsonStringPackType + ",");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Length " + cards.Count());

        // Console.WriteLine("Length " + JsonObject.Parse(cards);

        // Console.WriteLine("CARDS" + cards);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
{
"cardArray": [
    {
        "serialNumber": "23-1-0001",
        "cardName": "WWWame11",
        "edition": "first",
        "image": "https://image.com",
        "memberName": "Cris",
        "packType": "P1",
        "cardType": "MEMBER",
        "health": 100,
        "attack": 50
    },
    {
        "serialNumber": "23-1-0002",
        "cardName": "name22",
        "edition": "first",
        "image": "https://image.com",
        "memberName": "Denny",
        "packType": "P2",
        "cardType": "MEMBER",
        "health": 100,
        "attack": 50
    },
]
}
```

Comment: Try serializing all cards at once: `var jsonArrayString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cards.Values);`

Comment: Or to be more in line with your desired output json: `var desiredOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { cardArray = cards.Values });`

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved it and that was a huge help